# List all leaves of Huffman tree

Tags: list, append, scheme, huffman-code, r5rs

This is my Huffman coding that returns an empty list. My purpose was to make it add all the pairs to `listenr1` but it seams to only return an empty list. I'm not sure why it's not appending, but I think I have misunderstood a fundamental part of Scheme programming. I do not want to use `append*`. I think the appending might be wrong, but I'm not exactly sure why. Is there a way to replace `listenr1` each time it appends maybe?

```
(define (huffman-leafs tree)
  (let ((listenr1 '()))
    (define (iterator currentbranch)
      (let ((left (left-branch currentbranch))
            (right (right-branch currentbranch)))
        (if (leaf? left)
            (list (symbols left) (weight left))
            (append listenr1 (iterator left)))
        (if (leaf? right)
            (list (symbols right) (weight right))
            (append listenr1 (iterator right)))))
    (iterator tree)
    listenr1))

(huffman-leafs mytree)
```

Comment: you can `setf` result of `append`

Comment: If i do `var + 5` in any algol language, why dont `var` get increased by `5`?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written looks like a good start, but it's mixing recursive and non-recursive idioms.

The huffman tree is (I assume) either a LEAF? in which case it has SYMBOLS and WEIGHT. Otherwise it's got LEFT-BRANCH and RIGHT-BRANCH.

So we can define a single recursive function to list all the leaves like this:

```
(define (huffman-leafs tree)
  (if (leaf? tree)
      ;;; list this leaf alone
      ;;; else, use recursion (huffman-leafs (left-branch tree)) and right branch
      ;; and APPEND those together
      ))
```

Hope that helps!